# How to change a movieclips textfields from within the movieclip class?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a movieclip in my library named mcLeaderboarditem. I've generated a class for it to manage the textfields.

The easiest way is to make a child of the class and manage the contents properties with the dot-syntax like this (documentclass):

```
var leaderItem:mcLeaderboardItem = new mcLeaderboardItem();
leaderItem.lblRank.text = "2nd";
addChild(leaderItem);
```

This would make it easy for me, but i want to manage the data in the class so i can add aditional text to it (prefix / suffix / manipulations).
I've created several private properties: rank, displayname and score and change them from withing the documentClass with the getters and setters in mcLeaderboardItem. 
If i modify lblRank.text in the class and trace it, i see that it did modified the lblRankt.text but from the moment the compiler goes out of the class it takes again the default value of the label in the movieclip. 
Unless if i choose for the solution in the code block above. 
Code of the class mcLeaderboardItem:

```
package com.cleversprite.memorygame.ui 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class mcLeaderboardItem extends MovieClip 
{

    //VARIABLES
    //------------------------------------------------
    private var _rank:int;
    private var _displayname:String;
    private var _score:int;


    //PROPERTIES
    //------------------------------------------------
    public function get rank():int
    {
        return _rank;
    }

    public function set rank(v:int):void
    {
        _rank = v;
    }

    public function get displayname():String
    {
        return _displayname;
    }

    public function set displayname(v:String):void
    {
        _displayname = v;
    }

    public function get score():int
    {
        return _score;
    }

    public function set score(v:int):void
    {
        _score = v;
    }


    //CONSTRUCTOR
    //------------------------------------------------
    public function mcLeaderboardItem() 
    {
        super();
        init();
    }

    public function init():void
    {

        lblRank.text = String(_rank);
        lblDisplayname.text= _displayname;
        lblScore.text= String(_score);

    }
}
```

Does somebody see what i am doing wrong?
Probably it will be something stupid because of tiredness.
Or is there an other way to do what i'm trying to do?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: what does your documentclass look like? and do you have a `stop();` in it so that the code is only run once? normally when you change a value it shouldn't just switch back to the old one ...

Comment: I'm not certain on the question. Do you want the text fields to update when you set the `rank`, `displayname` and `score` properties?

Comment: @atonparker Yes indeed, thats what i'd like to do. For some reason he always set it to the default value unless i write the code like in the first code block (above).

Comment: @pkyeck The code in my documentclass looks like the first code block in my question. Soo, like this:
`var leaderItem:mcLeaderboardItem = new mcLeaderboardItem();
leaderItem.lblRank.text = "2nd";
addChild(leaderItem);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the setters to change the textfields each time they're called, it isn't enough to just set the text once within `init`. You'll have to set the text in each setter. A rewrite of your class like this should work:

```
public class mcLeaderboardItem extends MovieClip 
{
    public function mcLeaderboardItem() 
    {
       // These will set the initial text of the text fields now.
       rank = 0;
       displayname = "Default";
       score = 0;
    }

    public function get rank():int
    {
        return (lblRank.text as int);
    }

    public function set rank(v:int):void
    {
        lblRank.text = v;
    }

    public function get displayname():String
    {
        return lblDisplayname.text;
    }

    public function set displayname(v:String):void
    {
        lblDisplayname.text = v;
    }

    public function get score():int
    {
        return (lblScore.text as int);
    }

    public function set score(v:int):void
    {
        lblScore.text = v;
    }
}
```

Comment: THx for the help, pal.
At this moment i've found a solution myself with executing the init function after setting my properties in my DocumentClass.
Maybe your solution is even beter.
I will try it later on.

Comment: The functional difference between Cadin's and my solution is you'll just have to call the `init` function (maybe it should be called `update`) after you make changes to the leaderboard. Use whichever you feel comfortable with!

Comment: Init() is a basis method i always call in my constructor.
So making another function updateData() looks great to me ;-)

I might email my lector to know what he'd like i to do (he gives me points so his opinion is law ;-))

Comment: Be careful of having a public initialization function; the constructor is meant to fill that role. Also, in the future, if your question is for a class be sure to tag it with "homework"

Comment: Yes, i allready made my init function private and update the fields with an updateFields() method.
Where is the 'homework' tag for? I don't understand what 'homework' has to do with classes

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `init` from the class constructor, which means it runs and sets all the text fields before any of your data variables have a chance to get set (by calling the setters from the parent class). So it's just setting the text for all those text fields to null.

So,
you could either set the text for the appropriate text field inside the setter for that item, or just call init from your parent class AFTER you've set the data on the `mcLeaderboardItem`.

Something like this:

```
var leaderBoard:mcLeaderboardItem = new mcLeaderboardItem();
leaderBoard.rank = someRank;
leaderBoard.displayname = someName;
leaderBoard.init();
addChild(leaderBoard);
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer. But i'd allready found this out myself after an other guy told me the same thing like you did.

Cheers

Comment: You should still accept one of the answers if it is correct. Or post your own answer and accept that. It may be helpful to others in the future.